# ¿Como establezco una ruta diferente el helpers public_html() de laravel en laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel-5, hosting

Buenas chicos, el problema es el siguiente, intento guardar un archivo de imagen en la carpeta publica de un hosting, que he modificado, pero no me guarda la imagen en donde requiero, lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

En el hosting tengo la carpeta publica que se llama: `carpeta.com`, aquí guardo lo que contiene la carpeta `public`, y todos los demás archivos los guardo en otra carpeta llamada `carpeta`.

Ya realice los cambios en el index.php para que cargara el autoload.php de boostraps.php y el proyecto funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando intento almacenar la imagen, ya que me crea el directorio public/images_events/ en la `carpeta` y no en carpeta.com que es el public.

La manera en que guardo la imagen es la siguiente:

En el modelo:

```
 public function setImgAttribute($img){
    if (!empty($img)) {
    $name = Carbon::now()->second.$img->getClientOriginalName();
    $this->attributes['img'] = $name;
    \Storage::disk('local')->put($name, \File::get($img)); 
    }

}
```

Y en el Storage de filesystem.php tengo esto:

```
 'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path('images_events'),
    ],
```

Localmente me funciona perfectamente, pero el problema es que cuando crea en el hosting, no me almacena la imagen en `carpeta.com`, sino que crea la carpeta `public/images_events` y allí es donde almacena la imagen. He probado colocando en el index.php:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

En el metodo register de AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/../carpeta.com/';
    });
```

o:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/carpeta.com/';
        });
```

Y nada, si alguno tiene una idea de que podría hacer, lo agradecería!

Comment: Alguno tiene una idea chicos?

Comment: No me queda claro si carpeta es un subdirectorio de carpeta.com o si están al mismo nivel.

Comment: carpeta esta al mismo nivel que carpeta.com, confguro las variables del index.php del public para que me cargue el autoload y bootstrap y toda la cosa pero el problema es particularmente con la funcion Storage para guardar archivos... asumo que es por el public_html que es el que hace la ruta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como describes el problema, la solución debería ser utilizar `base_path()` en vez de `public_path()` en la configuración de filesystem:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => base_path('images_events'),
],
```

Comment: Revisare y te comento

Comment: chicos pudieron resolver ese problema, ami me esta apareciendo algo similar, necesito ayuda

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema y buscando soluciones me encontré con este post después de dos dias viendo tutoriales los cuales todos trabajan en modo local y otros en hosting compartidos, no pude dar con la solución pegando y copiando ya que mi hosting es el principal y gracias a Shaz que dio su respuesta pude sacar una idea de como hacer lo que yo necesitaba que era colocar, mi imagenes en public_html les dejo mi respuesta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo por favor lee [answer], el código te recomiendo como texto y no imagen